# How to improve my code to show a data array in a table, with TornadoFX?

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

This is my way to display an array of data:

```
private val data = observableArrayList(
        arrayOf("AAA", "111"),
        arrayOf("BBB", "222"),
        arrayOf("CCC", "333")
)

class HelloWorld : View() {
    override val root = tableview<Array<String>>(data) {
        column("name") { cellDataFeatures: TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Array<String>, String> -> 
            SimpleStringProperty(cellDataFeatures.value[0]) 
        }
        column("value") { cellDataFeatures: TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Array<String>, String> -> 
            SimpleStringProperty(cellDataFeatures.value[1]) 
        }
    }
}
```

It works but the code is quite complex. Is there any better way to do it?

(Maybe define a class to hold the data will make it much simpler, but I just want to test some uncommon cases)

Update:

A complete demo project for this: https://github.com/javafx-demos/tornadofx-tableview-array-data-demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simpler way of defining your columns:

```
class HelloWorld : View() {
    override val root = tableview(data) {
        column<Array<String>, String>("name", { it.value[0].toProperty() })
        column<Array<String>, String>("value", { it.value[1].toProperty() })
    }
}
```

That said, using a specialized data structure would yield less headache :)

An alternative approach would be to configure just the cell item type and then a value factory:

```
column("name", String::class) {
    value { it.value[0] }
}
column("value", String::class) {
    value { it.value[1] }
}
```

Comment: since the first type parameter `Array<String>` is already infered in `tableview(data)`, if we can find a way to simplify the calling to `column<String>("name", { it.value[0].toProperty() })`, it will be great

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative that includes less type noise :)